# Django Rest Framework Authentication Issues

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am a newbie in Django. I had created REST API using DRF. My Django has 3 apps. So now I want to apply authentication. I have seen much help but I am not to apply the authentication properly. I also want that the model should be attached to the user. So that one user can't see another user entries. Can anyone help me in telling how to implement this a little detailed?

Thanks in advance. Will be a great help if someone answers.

Comment: What have you tried so far?? Show some code..

Comment: I have included the owner with one of the model :
`owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='jobs', on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

In Views I have included:
`permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)`

Answer (score 1):

You could add custom permissions,

```
class IsOwnerOnlyAllowed(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.owner == request.user
```

You may add `permission_classes = (IsOwnerOnlyAllowed,)`

Also, you could override the `queryset` attribute of your view to provide only entries which are related to the logged in users.

Edit your views,

```
from rest_framework import generics 
from .models import DatasetModel 
from .serializer import DatasetSerializer 

class DatasetView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = DatasetModel.objects.all() 
    serializer_class = DatasetSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to do that?

Comment: `from rest_framework import generics
 from .models import DatasetModel
 from .serializer import DatasetSerializer

 class DatasetView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
     queryset=DatasetModel.objects.all()
     serializer_class = DatasetSerializer`